# Does physical system of smaller size necessarily takes shorter to reach a stable state / equilibrum?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Assume two systems A and B, both are governed by the same physics law, just the sizes are different.

Are their any counter examples or proof to this?

Comment: What sort of equilibrium are you interested in? mechanical? thermal? something else? What *exactly* do you mean by "only the sizes are different"?

Comment: Any kind of equilibrium. By size I mean literally the size, a bigger magnets vs smaller magnets, an ensemble of large volume vs small volume (same particle density), etc...

Comment: Voting to reopen. A perfectly clear questions, as is shown by the answers below.

Comment: Would small and large systems  that take the same time to equilibrate be a counter example? As @By-Symmetry notes, you should clarify what you mean by equilibrium. For example, different sized systems might take the same time to reach mechanical equilibrium, but heat up in the process and the larger system would take longer to cool down and reach ultimate thermal equilibrium.

Comment: Sorry for seeming pedantic, but "literally the size" is still ambiguous. For example, consider a balloon full of gas. Would a "smaller" balloon contain the same number of gas molecules but with smaller distances between them, or a smaller number of molecules with the same distance between them? Or would both count as smaller? Or would a radioactive atomic nucleus count as a system and would adding or removing nucleons count as making it larger or smaller? (I would guess not, and instead you would consider them different systems.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a beaker of water with an uneven surface. It will slosh around and come to equilibrium as gravity pulls it down and friction slows it.

Now repeat the experiment where everything, including Earth is smaller. Gravity is weaker, so the sloshing is slower. Friction doesn't change. This would take longer to come to equilibrium.

Comment: Nice example! Perhaps this could be generalized as a broader remark about driving and resistive forces scaling differently (a body force $\sim L^3$ vs. a surface force $\sim L^2$, say, where $L$ is the system size).

Comment: This may be true, but it is not trivially obvious to me. If everything is scaled down in size, then the size of the initial surface waves will also be smaller, which might compensate for the weaker gravity. As @Chemomechanics suggests, some discussion of the relevant scaling laws could clarify the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Time to reach equilibrium depends on initial conditions as well as on size.

A large container of gas in which the molecules' initial positions are randomly distributed is already at or very close to equilibrium. However, a smaller container of gas in which the molecules are initially confined to one half of the container will take longer to reach equilibrium, even though it is smaller than the first container.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I assume you imply that information can travel around in the system. Otherwise, if everything would stay strictly local, the size would obviously not matter at all.

Given this, it is clear that an equilibrium will only be established after the physical information from the border/edge of the system has been able to travel fully through the volume. This takes obviously time, and the more the larger the system is. For instance for a random walk of particles (like for gas molecules) the time to travel a net distance $d$ is proportional to $d^2$ (assuming the particle density is the same). In other physical scenarios the dependence may be proportional to $d$, but in any case size should matter here.